# Los parámetros con valores de tabla no están permitidos en llamadas remotas entre servidores SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Estoy tratando de llamar a un procedimiento almacenado remoto a través de un servidor vinculado. El problema es que uno de los parámetros requeridos es un tipo de tabla definido por el usuario.

Funciona perfectamente en el mismo servidor, pero cuando trato de ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado en el servidor vinculado, el SQL devuelve el siguiente error:

> Msg 7380, Level 16, State 1, Line 341 Table-valued parameters are not
> allowed in remote calls between servers.
>
> Completion time: 2023-04-19T11:58:03.1671023-06:00

Lo que hago es primero crear el tipo de tabla definido por el usuario en los dos servidores A y B:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[EmpClaveListV2] AS TABLE(
   [emp_clave] [varchar](15) not NULL
)
```

Luego llamo al procedimiento almacenado en el servidor B.

```
declare  @cur_clave_str varchar(250) = 'MX2020,EU2023'
declare @EmpData_Dummy [dbo].[EmpClaveListV2]
insert into @EmpData_Dummy (emp_clave)
(
       select '1' as emp union all
       select '2' as emp union all
       select '3' as emp union all
       select '4' as emp union all
       select '5' as emp union all
       select '6' as emp union all
       select '7' as emp union all
       select '8' as emp union all
       select '9' as emp union all
       select '10' as emp 
);

--/ Reporte  
exec [DBSourceServer].[SourceDWHTemp].[dbo].[dbo.Report_201873]
             @DateStart ='2023-03-01',
             @DateEnd= '2023-04-14', 
             @cur_clave_str = @cur_clave_str,
             @EmpData = @EmpData_Dummy
```

Estuve investigando y al parecer los parámetros con valores de tabla NO se admiten en todos los servidores ni son compatibles con las bases de datos en el mismo servidor, entonces quisiera preguntales que otras alternativas puedo realizar para poder ejecutar mi SP, estoy usando SQL Server 2016. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Por fortuna, tu caso es relativamente fácil de resolver, pues la tabla tiene un único campo y este campo, a pesar de ser de tipo varchar, parece contener valores numéricos. El método que te describo a continuación funcionará, incluso con datos alfanuméricos, siempre que ningún dato incluya el caracter coma (`','`).

Valiéndonos de lo dicho, puedes pasar la *tabla* como una lista dentro de un string, con los valores separados por comas:

Por ejemplo, la llamada quedaría así,

```
declare @empDataList as varchar(max);
set @empDataList = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10';

exec [DBSourceServer].[SourceDWHTemp].[dbo].[dbo.Report_201873L]
         @DateStart ='2023-03-01',
         @DateEnd= '2023-04-14', 
         @cur_clave_str = @cur_clave_str,
         @EmpDataList = @EmpDataList;
```

Estoy asumiendo aquí que en la base de datos remota existe un *nuevo* procedimiento llamado `Report_201873L` que recibirá el último parámetro de tipo varchar, y que contiene los datos del listado.

Como bono, para no tener que cambiar la lógica interna del procedimiento almacenado original y otras partes del sistema que dependan de él, podrías declarar este nuevo procedimiento para que cree una variable tipo tabla, llenarla con los datos recibidos en la lista y seguir llamando al procedimiento almacenado original, todo esto **dentro de la base de datos remota**, por ejemplo, para convertir la lista en una tabla, podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
create procedure Report_201873L (
    @DateStart date
  , @DateEnd date
  , @cur_clave_str varchar(250)
  , @EmpDataList varchar(max)
)
as 
begin
  declare @EmpDataTable [dbo].[EmpClaveListV2];

  with
  tmp(Item, Remanente) as (
  select   left(@EmpDataList, charindex(',', @EmpDataList + ',') -1)
         , stuff(@EmpDataList, 1, charindex(',', @EmpDataList + ','), '')
  union all
  select   left(Remanente, charindex(',', Remanente + ',') -1)
         , stuff(Remanente, 1, charindex(',', Remanente + ','), '')
    from tmp
   where Remanente > ''
  )
  insert into @empDataTable
  select Item as emp_clave
    from tmp
  option (maxrecursion 2000);

  exec dbo.Report_201873
         @DateStart = @DateStart,
         @DateEnd = @DateEnd, 
         @cur_clave_str = @cur_clave_str,
         @EmpData = @EmpDataTable;
end;
```

El CTE `tmp` va extrayendo, de manera recursiva, los datos de la lista y los devuelve como una tabla.

Vale la pena aclarar que el método propuesto, al compararlo con el original, tiene la limitante de no ser capaz de manejar una lista con muchos datos, como si es capaz la tabla, debido a dos motivos:

- Está basado en un CTE recursivo, y hay un límite a dicha recursividad. Utilizo para ello el *hint* `maxrecursion` al hacer uso de dicho CTE, pero puede ser que en un servidor de producción no puedas extenderlo tanto.
- La longitud máxima de la cadena. `Varchar(max)` equivale a `Varchar(8000)`. En mis pruebas, pude acomodar un listado de 1821 números (del 1 al 1821) en dicha cadena.

Comment: Entiendo mas o menos lo que me comentas, solo que el ultimo parametro que recibe si es Table ReadOnly, el procedimiento almacenado no lo puedo modificar yo por eso estoy buscando distintas maneras de ejecutarlo

Comment: Lo bueno es que, con lo que te he sugerido, no tienes que modificar el procedimiento original. Por otro lado, esas limitantes se dicen **de entrada** en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Los [Table-Valued Parameters](https://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html#CLR:%7E:text=reflects%20the%20contents.-,Table%2DValued%20Parameters,-in%20T%E2%80%91SQL) son tipo de datos que efectivamente no pueden usarse entre servidores remotos, incluso en teoría, tampoco entre bases en un mismo servidor, por algo el TYPE se crea en cada base.

Si estás usando SQL Server v2016 o superior, y además las bases tienen la compatibilidad en está versión, la forma más natural de hacer esto, o sea, trasladar una estructura de datos compleja de un servidor a otro, es mediante la serialización/des-serialización JSON. O sea, transformamos los datos en una cadena tipo JSON, pasamos como parámetro esta cadena y luego, en el servidor remoto, se transforma la cadena nuevamente en una tabla. Cuidado, está mecánica aplica a conjuntos acotados de datos, no debiera usarse para trasladar tablas o consultas complejas, dónde hay otros métodos mejores.

```
-- Serializar una tabla en un Objeto JSON
--
DECLARE @EmpData_Dummy NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @EmpData_Dummy = 
(
    SELECT * from
    (
    select '1' as emp union all
    select '2' as emp union all
    select '3' as emp union all
    select '4' as emp union all
    select '5' as emp union all
    select '6' as emp union all
    select '7' as emp union all
    select '8' as emp union all
    select '9' as emp union all
    select '10' as emp
    ) y
    FOR JSON PATH
)
select @EmpData_Dummy
[{"emp": "1"},{"emp": "2"},{emp": "3"},{"emp": "4"},{"emp": "5"},{"emp": "6"},{"emp": "7"},
 {"emp": "8"},{"emp": "9"},{"emp": "10"}]
```

La variable `@EmpData_Dummy` se pasá como parámetro y en el servidor remoto hay que des-serializar para obtener nuevamente una tabla:

```
-- Desserialización
SELECT  emp
    FROM OPENJSON ( @EmpData_Dummy )  
    WITH (   
        emp int          '$.emp'  
    )
```

Importante: lo recalco por las dudas, `OPENJSON` funciona en bases cuya compatibilidad sea 2016 o superior.